# redirect or rewrite /user/xx links to a module page

Tags: users, redirection

This should be easy to do, but its very hard to Google.

Within the admin and surrounding workflows, various links point to user/foobar. I have a different page to display users, say /faces/xx. I want to intercept (or rewrite) every url linking to user/foobar/ to faces/xx.

Pathauto lets you customize what paths user profiles have. If I set that to /faces/[user:uid], it will create aliases overriding my module router; so that faces/xx looks the same as user/foobar previously did. That is *not* what I want.

You can redirect users on login or other triggers. That is also *not* what I am looking for.

Most likely, I can override something in my module that intercepts user/foobar calls and does a `drupal_goto('faces/xx')`. Or there is a url_alter that I can override that writes out the user/foobar links. That, or something similar, is what Im looking for.

EDIT -- sample code from the module that generates the faces page

```
function faces_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['faces/%'] = array(
        'title'             => t('Face'),
        'access callback'   => true, // more complex in reality
        'page callback'     => 'faces_page',
        'page arguments'    => array(1,2),
        'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
function faces_page($uid) {
    global $user;
    $output =  array(
        'faces-page' => array(
            'magic'     => voodoo($uid),
            '#theme'    => 'faces_pages'
        )
    );      
    return $output;
}
```

and ofcourse theres a faces_theme() to match it.

Comment: Why is aliasing not acceptable?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)

Comment: @Geoff aliasing would be acceptable, as long as the end point of the link is my module page (pathauto doesnt do that)

Comment: @Clive, yes url_inbound_alter might help. i've updated the question a bit to illustrate why i cant easily use it: drupal links to `user/[username]` and I want to link to `faces/[uid]`; so I would have to resolve [username], probably with urlencoding,  to [uid]

Comment: If I understand your question I would recommend trying the globalredirect module. Does that meet your needs?

Comment: and what is the end-goal? what does your module do with the end page? perhaps there's an alternative way of accomplishing what you want, without having to resort to a redirect

Comment: @rooby - i dont see how globalredirect could help. i already have pathauto and nice urls / url aliases.

Comment: @geoff the end goal is to show faces/xx instead, which is a module view. it connects to voodoo services to return sheer magic, which you can't do from a template.

Comment: well actually, you can do just about anything from a template... whether or not you should is a whole other question. Then I would suggest modifying the module, turn it into a custom module and adjust it to suit Drupals behaviour, instead of trying to get Drupal to suit the module

Comment: @geoff - it is a custom module. I'd like to adjust it to suit drupals behaviour if I can; any suggestions ?

Comment: you would have to show code - since we don't know how it's set up now, no one would know how to adjust it to suit. Presumably there's a hook, perhaps a page alter with a callback based on the url. Do a search for 'faces' in the code and show the function it is in, or at least a few lines above and below it

Comment: dont have to search, i wrote the module. pretty standard, updated the question

Comment: yup... well, you can do a redirect in hook_boot() or a number of other hooks, but depending on what voodoo() returns, I might first try implementing this in hook_user_view() or hook_user_view_alter() with the existing pathauto alias

Answer (score 0):

d'oh! thanks to @geoff above .. this seems to work (in a module called 'faces')

```
function faces_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if ($view_mode=='full') {
        drupal_goto('faces/'.$account->uid);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually meant to include the results of voodoo() here to build the user profile, not the redirect, but hey, if it works :)